# HTMLElement.offsetTop doesn't work in subpixel precision

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am writing a small program where I move `DOM`s at a specified speed.

When I move it at the rate of `20px per second`, the `offset` that gets added to the `elem.style.top` is about `0.3px per frame`.

The problem is, when this `offset` is smaller than `0.5px`, `elem` doesn't move!

I constructed a simplified example that can demonstrate the issue in my program:

```js
var requestFrameAnimationId;

function myMove(offset) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  requestFrameAnimationId = animationLoop(frame);
  function frame() {
    console.log(elem.offsetTop);
    if (elem.offsetTop === 350) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(requestFrameAnimationId);
    } else {
      elem.style.top = elem.offsetTop + offset + 'px'; 
      elem.style.left = elem.offsetLeft + offset + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}

function animationLoop(render) {
    var running, lastFrame = +new Date(); // casting Date to Number
    function loop(now) {`enter code here`
      requestFrameAnimationId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      running = render(now - lastFrame);
      lastFrame = now;
    }
    loop(lastFrame);
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      <button onclick="myMove(0.3)">Move at 0.3px per frame</button>
      <button onclick="myMove(0.5)">Move at 0.5px per frame</button>
    </p>

    <div id="container">
    <div id="animate"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try clicking on `Move at 0.5px per frame`. The rectangle should be moving.
Reset it by clicking on `Run code snippet`.

Now try clicking on `Move at 0.3px per frame`.
It should be moving the DOM more slowly, but you can see that the DOM is not moving.

It's strange because when I initially kept track of the `top` position in a javascript variable `topPos`, and applied `${topPos + offset}` to `elem.style.top`, it worked at even slower speeds!

So my guess is that `elem.offsetTop` rounds the decimal values, so 0.3 becomes 0, and 0.5 becomes 1.

What can I do to make it so that the DOM moves precisely at the specified speed? I can't use any libraries for this one.

---

EDIT: I looked more into the problem and I believe it's `offsetTop` that rounds the numbers to integers.

However, I found out that CSS OM spec changed the type of `offsetTop` to `float`, and [the Chromium team was working on applying the change on the browser more than 4 years ago, and it seems that it should be fixed by now](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360889).

Why is it not working on my program, and how can I make it work?

---

EDIT2: I found from [CSSOM working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#scrolloptionsvertical) that the type of `offsetTop` was integer.

```
readonly attribute long offsetTop;
```

I think they only changed the type of `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` to a double precision number.

```
attribute unrestricted double scrollTop;
attribute unrestricted double scrollLeft;
```

Comment: `style.top/left = ...px` works with integers only, decimals are rounded before use.

Comment: @Teemu that's not true. Please run this and jsfiddle.net/pjf0gny7/1 see the console log. The problem is with `offsetTop`, not `style.top`.

Comment: Mhh ... the values are stored as they're entered, but internally the style is set with integers ("_... works with integers ..._"). Just change `pos+=0.01` in your fiddle, and you can see, that the element is moving pixel by pixel, not by 1/100 of a pixel.

Comment: @Teemu I just tried incrementing by `0.01`. If you see this recording https://imgur.com/a/EaJzK, the rectangle is moving by 0.01px every frame. Please let me know if this was not what you meant.

Comment: ??? In the recording the red block is moving one pixel per every 100 execution. The value of `pos` changes 99 times, then the block is moved by a one single whole pixel ... `style` can't place elements in fractional positions.

Comment: @Teemu Ahh, it makes sense now. Thank you. But still, I don't need `0.01px` precision, and it's at least incrementing values by 0.01 and moving when they add up to 1. As long as I can increment the value by 0.3 every frame, and if it can move every 3~4 frames, that will move the DOM at about 20px per second. I want to figure out how to accomplish this...

Comment: @Teemu little correction, style can place at fractional values, the culprit here is `HTMLElement.offsetXXX` which is indeed rounded. Using getBoundingClientRect, you would have the fractional values.

Comment: @Kaiido Please can you show me how __to place to__ a fractional position using style?.

Comment: @Teemu elem.style.lengthProp = '2em' or 'anyvalue%' or 'n.123px' Some properties / methods that will serialize these values will get rounded, some UAs may ignore the floating values while painting, but the value stored is not.

Comment: @Kaiido yes, you can set the value, but the placing happens by pixel, you can't place an element in between two pixels using style, though even fractional value is stored to the length properties.

Comment: @Teemu that is implementation dependent. Blink (and webkit?)  normally won't, Gecko (FF) will. And even in Blink, it can actually [be achieved](https://jsfiddle.net/j6yqzako/) with the transform property.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm on FF, and couldn't get fractional placement, not even with transform ...

Comment: @Teemu seems you are right, I guess it changed quite recently (probably with quantum). But [they still take floating values into account](https://jsfiddle.net/j6yqzako/1/).

Comment: @Kaiido Well, I've to admit, that I already wrote "use transform" into my first comment in this thread, but luckily tested it before posting the comment. And my test surprisingly couldn't place an element to fractional places.

Comment: @Teemu I am 80.1% sure that less than a year ago, you could do it with any length in FF and 99.9% sure that you could at least set border-width to such a floating point value.

Comment: @Kaiido I can only agree with this all, plus also transform, but the behavior seems to have been changed lately. There've been something big going on with the smooth scrolling on many browsers, maybe this is a part of the job ...

Comment: I learned a lot from you guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HTMLElement.offset[Left | Top]](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#ref-for-dom-htmlelement-offsetleft) return `long` typed value (i.e integer).

Use [Element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) if you want float values.

```js
var requestFrameAnimationId;

    function myMove(offset) {
      var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
      requestFrameAnimationId = animationLoop(frame);

      function frame() {
        // build up our own high precision offsetTop
        var parentRect = elem.offsetParent && elem.offsetParent.getBoundingClientRect() || {top: 0, left:0};
       var elemRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
        var rect = {
          top: elemRect.top - parentRect.top,
          left: elemRect.left - parentRect.left
        };
        if (rect.top >= 350) {
          cancelAnimationFrame(requestFrameAnimationId);
        } else {
          // so we can substract it here
          elem.style.top = (rect.top + offset) + 'px';
          elem.style.left = (rect.left + offset) + 'px';
        }
      }
    }

    function animationLoop(render) {
      var running, lastFrame = +new Date(); // casting Date to Number
      function loop(now) {
        requestFrameAnimationId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        running = render(now - lastFrame);
        lastFrame = now;
      }
      loop(lastFrame);
    }
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick="myMove(0.3)">Move at 0.3px per frame</button>
  <button onclick="myMove(0.5)">Move at 0.5px per frame</button>
</p>

<div id="container">
  <div id="animate"></div>
</div>
```

Or simply add up your values to a variable:

```js
var requestFrameAnimationId;

function myMove(offset) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  requestFrameAnimationId = animationLoop(frame);
  var pos = 0;

  function frame() {
    pos += offset;
    if (pos >= 350) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(requestFrameAnimationId);
    } else {
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}

function animationLoop(render) {
  var running, lastFrame = +new Date(); // casting Date to Number
  function loop(now) {
    requestFrameAnimationId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    running = render(now - lastFrame);
    lastFrame = now;
  }
  loop(lastFrame);
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick="myMove(0.3)">Move at 0.3px per frame</button>
  <button onclick="myMove(0.5)">Move at 0.5px per frame</button>
</p>

<div id="container">
  <div id="animate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but I guess you are not using the `rect` value? I tried using `elem.getBoundingClientRect().top`, but it was not working as I intended. Could you use my code snippet from the question, rather than the jsfiddle I uploaded, which uses `pos` variable, and not get it from the `elem`?

Comment: @EricNa yes sorry forgot to add the *Or simply add up your values to a variable* line...

Comment: I already had a working version where I was using a variable. I was trying to get the `top` position from the `elem`, and that was why I posted this question. Could you please show me how to use `getBoundingClientRect()` for the snippet in my question? I really appreciate it.

Comment: When I do `elem.style.top = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + offset + 'px';`, it moves too quickly... it disappears within a second.

Comment: @EricNa Yes because your element already have an offset, so you need to grab the initial one and substract it from the next position at every frames, I'll add an example in the answer

Comment: Ahh thanks a lot!! I can see that it works now. However, when I scroll, `elem` moves together because `getBoundingClientRect` returns the position relative to its viewport, which also depends on scrolling. So I guess it's not reliable for my use case, even though my use case doesn't need scroll at this time.

Comment: I fixed the scrolling issue, didn't saw `elem` was relative to #container... gBR is relative to the doc, so we need to substract #container's own rect to our final rect. Edited But the variable is definitely the more clear and less prone to error way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, I see that it's getting convoluted. Keeping a variable definitely seems like a cleaner way.